# VisualStudio code doesn't detect TypeScript Array type

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using **VSCode** in **Ubuntu 16.04**, with **TypeScript 2.0.2**, and this happens:

[image: Math not found]

But the app works perfectly. It's a vscode problem. It happens with other types, like Array.

Should I install a plugin? I've installed [TypeScript Hero](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbbit.typescript-hero)

**UPDATE: Here, my tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using a tsconfig?

Comment: Yes. Check the update :)